How to apply a threshold filter to a layer?
Having an array like this :
input = np.array([[0.04, -0.8, -1.2, 1.3, 0.85, 0.09, -0.08, 0.2]])

I want to change all the values (of the last dimension) between -0.1 and 0.1 to zero and change the rest to 1
filtred = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]]

Using the lamnda layer is not my favor choice (I would prefer to find a solution with a native layer which could be easily converted to TfLite without activating the SELECT_TF_OPS or the TFLITE_BUILTINS options) but I tried it anyway :
layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: 0 if x <0.1 and x>-0.1 else 1)
layer(input)

I am getting :
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling Lambda.call().

The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Arguments received by Lambda.call():
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(6,), dtype=float32)
  • mask=None
  • training=None


This is doing the job
def func(x):
    abs = tf.keras.backend.abs(x)
    greater = tf.keras.backend.greater(abs, 0.1) 
    return tf.keras.backend.cast(greater, dtype=tf.keras.backend.floatx()) #will return boolean values
     
layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(func)
input = np.array([[0.04, -0.8, -1.2, 1.3, 0.85, 0.09, -0.08, 0.2]])
layer(input)

